# Error propagation with NDSolve and periodic boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, precision-and-accuracy, error-propagation

I'm trying to solve the problem of heat conduction through soil with periodic temperature variations on the surface.
For now I'm working with a 1D model but I see that the solution doesn't work, it seems that there is some kind of error due to the numerical algorithms used by Mathematica, do you know how to fix that?
My code is like that:

```
a = 20 (*a= years *)
h = 20(*  h= bottom of the simulation*)
s = 365*24*60*60(*s=time in seconds of one year *)
c = 37(* c=cave depth in meters *)
k = 0.756*10^(-6)(*  k=thermal diffusivity*)
d = 20(* d= difference outside and inside temperatures*)
p = (s)(* p= period in seconds of the oscillation*)
delta = 60*60*24*1(*delta= interval for time evaluation*)

sol2 = 
  NDSolve[
   {D[u[t, x], t] == k*D[u[t, x], x, x],    
    u[0, x] == 0, u[t, 0] == d*Sin[ 2 Pi/p t], D[u[t, h], x] == -u[t, h]},
    u, {t, 0, a*s}, {x, 0, h}, 
   Method -> 
     {"MethodOfLines", 
        "SpatialDiscretization" -> 
          {"TensorProductGrid", "DifferenceOrder" -> Pseudospectral"}}];

Print[
  "Period of the output temperature oscillation in days:    ", 
  FunctionPeriod[Sin[2 Pi/p t], t]/60/60/24 // N]

Manipulate[
  Plot[u[t, x] /. sol2, {x, 0, 20}, 
    PlotRange -> {-d, d}, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"], 
  {t, 0, a*s, delta}]

Manipulate[
  Plot[u[t, x] /. sol2, {t, 0, a*s}, 
    PlotRange -> Automatic, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"], 
  {x, 0, h}]

Manipulate[
  Plot[u[t, x] /. sol2, {t, 0, a*s}, 
    PlotRange -> Automatic, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"], 
  {{x, 10.65}, 0, 20}]
```

How you can see from the  graph if you move along the x axes the values get wronger and wronger, since I would expect a mean value around 0, instead of this strange behaviour with increased temperature at the beginning.
I suspect that the problem is linked with the absolute value of the k constant, in fact setting k=1 we don't have the initial anomaly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I took the tour and i found it very useful.

Comment: What about these results is wrong?  Your graphs show that in the long-term the average temperature at each location seems to be zero, which makes sense given your forcing.  The initial dynamics will depend on your initial temperature distribution, which you set constant but that doesn't match the long-term distribution at the beginning of a period.

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't call these "periodic boundary conditions", which usually implies periodic w/ space so that `u[t,0]=u[t,h]` and `u'[t,0]=u'[t,h]`.

Comment: Hi, they are wrong because we have this big peak in the beginning instead of oscillations around 0... I edited the image to explain better the problem.

Comment: And most important, I suspect that the problem is related to the small value of the constant k, infact if I set k=1 we don't have the initial anomaly...

Comment: My intuition is that this solution is in fact correct.  Try plotting the spatial distribution of temperature over the first couple cycles with `Do[Print[Plot[u[f s, x] /. sol2, {x, 0, h}, PlotRange -> {-20, 20}, PlotLabel -> f]], {f, 0, 2, 0.1}];`  In the first cycle, the surface initially warms and this temperature diffuses down, so the deeper temperature has no choice but to increase.  After a few cycles, you see that the temperature distribution at the beginning of a period is not constant as in your initial conditions.

Comment: I respectfully think that your intuition is wrong in that case. In fact changing the k parameter we see that at the same depth there isn't the same problem, and the k parameter changes only the speed of heat propagation. (no problems with k=1)

Comment: What do you expect if you speed up heat conduction by 6 orders of magnitude? You can't tell the lack of symmetry by looking at a graph with a `k` that high. it takes time to reach the steady state, and how much time depends on k.  Try repeatedly doubling `k` to see how it affects the time it takes at, say `x == 10`.

Comment: I still think that the problem arise from numeric methods, since the problem present a very high degree of simmetry... Thank you both for your help anyway.

Comment: Check your code `D[u[t, h], x] == -u[t, h]`.  The LHS is zero, because there is no `x` in `u[t, h]`.  Perhaps you want `(D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> h) == -u[t, h]`, because you have to differentiate before you plug in.

Comment: @MichaelE2 is `D[u[t, x], t] - k D[u[t, x], x, x] == NeumannValue[-u[t, x], x == h]` the same as what you suggested?

Comment: @Young Does `NeumannValue[]` work with non-FEM methods?  I'm not sure I've ever tried it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I don't think so ... I also changed `Method` to `{"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
 "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
   "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1}}}` ... I was just checking if I was using `NeumannValue` correctly

Comment: @MichaelE2 The results seem very different for smaller values of `h` so I guess they aren't equivalent.